# How TO SELECT DISTINCT records in mysql uisng JOIN on four tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have four tables named college_list, course_list, branch_list, semester_list. And have applied JOIN on these tables as under.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
       LEFT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
       LEFT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
       LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code GROUP BY bran_name
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
       RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
       LEFT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
       LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code GROUP BY bran_name
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
       RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
       RIGHT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
       LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code GROUP BY bran_name
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
       RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
       RIGHT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
       RIGHT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code GROUP BY bran_name
```

The result of this query is as below.

[image]

But I want the college name to come for once. And same with other columns.
So how can I use GROUP BY or DISTINCT commands to get so?

Comment: Group by is best for this work

Comment: but its not working

Comment: can you plz tell me the way to use it

Comment: you can do multiple group by clauses. just use `GROUP BY col1, col2`

Comment: @Takarii can you plz tell me the way to use it. Bcz its showing error when i used that

Comment: thats exactly how its used. extra columns in the group by seperated by commas.

Comment: @Takarii see the answer given below by tapos. What changes can i make in that answer?

Comment: try using  `GROUP BY bran_name, college_list.clg_name` in each of your queries

Comment: sorry none of the answers is working

Comment: any other answers plz

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have the data from your tables, I am not able to test my solution. I suggest the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
       LEFT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
       LEFT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
       LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
       RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
       LEFT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
       LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
       RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
       RIGHT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
       LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
       RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
       RIGHT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
       RIGHT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code) AS TEMP GROUP BY clg_name, crs_name, bran_name, sem_name
```

You first combine the separate queries, forming a virtual table, then select from this table grouping by all columns. You want to group the whole result set, not separately by each of the 4 queries.

Comment: see when i used the above code its showing "College 1College 1College 1College 1College 1College 2..." and so on...But i want only distinct college names i.e "College 1 College2"

Comment: Okay, then group by clg_name only. But then you will lose all the courses except one (and you do not know which one - it will be chosen randomly by the database), and all the branches except one (again randomly chosen), and all the semesters except one (again randomly chosen). So why bother to show any other columns beyond College name ? May be you only want to show colleges with at least one course ? Then you need another query. If you need to know the semester of all courses in all branches in all colleges - this is the right query.

Answer (score 0):

Write  this code I think your problem will be solved

```
 SELECT  college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
                    LEFT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
                    LEFT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
                    LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code GROUP BY bran_name
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
                    RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
                    LEFT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
                    LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code GROUP BY bran_name
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
                    RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
                    RIGHT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
                    LEFT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code GROUP BY bran_name
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT DISTINCT college_list.clg_name, course_list.crs_name, branch_list.bran_name, semester_list.sem_name FROM college_list 
                    RIGHT JOIN course_list ON college_list.clg_code = course_list.crs_clg_code
                    RIGHT JOIN branch_list ON course_list.crs_code = branch_list.bran_crs_code
                    RIGHT  JOIN semester_list ON branch_list.bran_crs_code = semester_list.sem_crs_code GROUP BY bran_name

                    group by college_list.clg_name
```

Comment: sorry its showing an error